# Binary Tree Comparison & Recursive Insertion

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm having an issue with comparing the root and the value that will be inserted.

I'm trying to read in names from a txt file and build a binary tree (comparing alphabetically).

Problem I see is that root->name and value->name become the same which should not be happening.

For example,

if the names in the txt file are:

```
alex
brian
chris
```

at first, because rootNode is NULL, insert function should change its root name to alex.
Then it should compare new name(brian) to the rootnode's name(alex).
Then set the new node(brian) to the rightNode of the rootNode(alex). but it does't seem to be doing that.

What am I doing wrong? 
How would I approach this problem?

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct binaryTree{
    char* name;
    struct binaryTree* leftNode;
    struct binaryTree* rightNode;
};


struct binaryTree* insert(struct binaryTree* root, struct binaryTree* value);
struct binaryTree* init(char* val);
int main() {
    struct binaryTree* rootNode = NULL;
    char name[100];
    int numWords;
    int searchNum;
    int deleteNum;

    struct binaryTree* tempNode;

    FILE *fPtr;
    if ((fPtr = fopen("in.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error. No File Found");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        fscanf(fPtr, "%d", &numWords);
        fscanf(fPtr, "%d", &searchNum);
        fscanf(fPtr, "%d", &deleteNum);
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", numWords, searchNum, deleteNum);

    for (int i = 0; i <numWords; i ++){
        fscanf(fPtr, "%s", name);
        tempNode = init(name);
        rootNode = insert(rootNode, tempNode);

    }
    return 0;
}

struct binaryTree* insert(struct binaryTree* root, struct binaryTree* value){
    if (root == NULL){
        printf("value = %s\n",value->name);
        return value;
    }
    else{
        if(strcmp(root->name, value->name)>0){
            if(root->rightNode != NULL){
                printf("inserting right");
                root->rightNode = insert(root->rightNode,value);
            }
            else{
                root->rightNode = value;
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(root->name, value->name)<0){
            printf("inserting left\n");
            if(root->leftNode != NULL){
                root->leftNode = insert(root->leftNode,value);
            }
            else{
                root->leftNode = value;
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("the names are same");
        }
        return root;
    }
}

struct binaryTree* init(char* val){
    struct binaryTree* temp;
    temp = (struct binaryTree*)malloc(sizeof(struct binaryTree));
    temp->name = val;
    temp->leftNode = NULL;
    temp->rightNode = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Format your code correctly.

Comment: You have two `insert` routines but no `main` or anything that calls the (those?) `insert` routines. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the problem you're asking about. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex Oh These two calls that follow each other does not make sense.         tempNode = init(name);
        rootNode = insert(rootNode, tempNode); The tree shall be initialized by setting the pointer root to NULL. Thai is all.

Comment: @Alex Oh And you must to allocate memory for a name and copy the name to the allocated memory instead of this assignment temp->name = val;